# NO setter property found in class Spring

Tags: spring, applicationcontext

I have a spring application and deploying in external `tomcat`(version-8.0.0).Using `STS` ide for development.

**applicationContext.xml**

```
  <bean id="Manager" class="com.data.managers.Manager" p:hostName="${hostName}"
             p:userName="${username}"  p:pWord="${password}">
   </bean>
```

**Manager Class**

```
public class Manager {

    private String pWord;
    

    public void setpWord(String pWord) {
        this.pWord = pWord;
    }
}
```

When i build the application,**applicationContext** file showing error

```
No setter found for property 'pWord' in class com.data.managers.Manager
```

what was wrong here.

Help me to solve this issue

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getter and Setter for `pWord` should be `getPWord()` and `setPWord()`. The first letter after `set` and `get` should be uppercase.

Better change the property to `password` and getter setter to `getPassword` and `setPassword`

Comment: @ Karthikeyan Vaithilingam, Thanks for the quick replay.